# How to Setup Masternode for Beginners?

Tags: blockchain, geek

guide is for a single masternode, on a Ubuntu 16.04 64bit server (VPS) running headless and will be controlled from the wallet on your local computer (Control wallet)

Comment: What is a masternode? What software or cryptocurrency project is this about?

Comment: Pls visit here: https://medium.com/@DanielJenkinson/an-introduction-and-guide-to-masternodes-1832fecd8ab5

Comment: Do you want a Dash or a GeekCash masternode?